# Printing Named Ranges by selecting from a list of named ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet that contains approx 50 Named Ranges and I create a list of those named Ranges which contain data and hence need to be printed. The names of those containing data are stored in a column. I need to use these names as Print Areas in a macro to loop through and print each of these ranges on a separate page. My problem is how to select each Cell Value to use as the name of a Print Area. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Select the Cells and run this macro. It will loop through all the values and print the named ranges.

```
Sub printSelectedNamedRanges()
Dim rng as Range
set rng = Selection.Range
For Each cell In rng.Cells
   shName = Range(cell.Value).Parent.Name
   ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shName).Activate
   Range(cell.Value).PrintOut 
Next
End Sub
```

---

You can add this on top of previous code if You have named ranges in another named Range.

```
namedRange = "Put your main Named Range here "
sheetName = Range(namedRange).Parent.Name
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName).Activate
Range(namedRange).Select
```

So in you case the code will be

```
Sub printSelectedNamedRanges()
Dim rng as Range

namedRange = "Put your main Named Range here "
sheetName = Range(namedRange).Parent.Name
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName).Activate

set rng =  Range(namedRange)
For Each cell In rng.Cells
   shName = Range(cell.Value).Parent.Name
   ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shName).Activate
   Range(cell.Value).PrintOut 
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you select the cells by naming the range they are in ?

Comment: Yes i have updated the answer for that case

Comment: It works great. Your assistance is very much appreciated

Comment: Can you accept the answer than

Answer (score 0):

### Print Named Ranges From a List

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub PrintNamedRangesFromList()
 
    ' Define constants.
    Const SRC_WORKSHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const SRC_FIRST_CELL As String = "A2"
    
    ' Reference the workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the source single-column range (containing the names).
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_WORKSHEET_NAME)
    Dim sfCell As Range: Set sfCell = sws.Range(SRC_FIRST_CELL)
    Dim slCell As Range
    Set slCell = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, sfCell.Column).End(xlUp)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range(sfCell, slCell)
    
    ' For each cell of the source range, print the range
    ' defined by its name contained in the cell.
    ' Account for not existing names and names not referring to a range.
    ' Log the process ('Debug.Print') in the Immediate window (Ctrl+G).
    
    Dim sCell As Range, prg As Range, pName As Name, pString As String
    
    For Each sCell In srg.Cells
        
        pString = CStr(sCell.Value)
        
        On Error Resume Next ' prevent error if name not found
            Set pName = wb.Names(pString)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        If Not pName Is Nothing Then ' name found
            
            On Error Resume Next ' prevent error if name not a range
                Set prg = pName.RefersToRange
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not prg Is Nothing Then ' name is a range
                prg.PrintOut
                Debug.Print "The range """ & pName.Name & """ referring to """ _
                    & pName.RefersTo & """ was processed."
                Set prg = Nothing ' reset for the next iteration
            Else ' name is not a range
                Debug.Print "The name """ & pName.Name & """ refers to """ _
                    & pName.RefersTo & """ and was not processed."
            End If
            
            Set pName = Nothing ' reset for the next iteration
        
        Else ' name not found
            
            Debug.Print "The name """ & pString & """ was not found."
        
        End If
    
    Next sCell
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Named ranges printed.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: This works very well but could I ask where I can add code to print in Landscape